# How do I create a List of lists (matrix) containing different variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working with the Python language and I am trying to create a class that acts as a matrix containing 4 parallel lists with a length that is equal to the length of a given sentence. Each list will have its own row and will contain different variables. However I am having troubles trying to print out each individual letter of the sentence into row 2. How would I go about achieving this through iteration (rather than manually appending them)?

For visual purposes, the end result will need to look like this:

```
Row 1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Row 2 = [h, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d]
Row 3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Row 4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Below is my current code.

```
class Matrix(object):#,Sentence, Cipher_Sentence
    def __init__ (self, cols, rows):#, Nav):#, Guess, Crypt, Sent):
        self.cols=cols
        self.rows=rows
        self.sentence=sentence
        self.matrix=[]
        for i in range (rows):
            ea_row=[]
            for j in range (cols):
                ea_row.append(0)
            self.matrix.append(ea_row)

    def set_Nav(self, col, row, Nav):
        self.matrix[col-1][0]=Nav
    def get_Nav(self, col, row):
        return self.matrix[col-1][0]

    def set_Guess(self, col, row, Guess):
        self.matrix[col-1][1]=Guess
    def get_Guess(self, col, row):
        return self.matrix[col-1][1]

    def set_Crypt(self, col, row, Crypt):
        self.matrix[col-1][2]=Crypt
    def get_Crypt(self, col, row):
        return self.matrix[col-1][2]

    def set_Sent(self, col, row, Sent):
        self.matrix[col-1][3]=Sent
    def get_Sent(self, col, row):
        return self.matrix[col-1][3]

    def __repr__(self):
        rowname= ""
        for i in range(self.rows):
            rowname += 'Row %s = %s\n' %(i+1, self.matrix[i])

        return rowname
sentence="hello world"
m=Matrix(len(sentence),4)
print(m)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give more details about what those functions are supposed to do? Why can't you just use a two-dimensional list?

Comment: Certainly. My overall program is a Cryptogram.  This current class is supposed to produce an item that has 4 different variables in it: 
Sent:
A String variable that is consists of a  randomly selected sentence. Each character of this sentence should be input into one of the rows (for arguments sake, Row 2) 

Crypt:
This is a Cryptographic version of the sentence.
Guess:
This is the guess value the user inputs. It will be compared with the sentence and if correct, will set Nav to 1.
Nav:
A boolean variable of 0 or 1 that determines whether a successfully guessed letter exists in  Guess.

Comment: As it stands, I am simply trying to ensure that each row is presenting the appropriate variables, which will later be called from into a GUI (using Tkinter). The Nav variable is designed to prevent Navigation  through a series of entry fields  if a correct guess has been inserted.

Comment: @Xecron It's still not at all clear what you are trying to do. Your code currently doesn't put "hello world" into the 2nd row at all. Can you maybe modify the code so that it does what you want it to do with the "manually added" method that you allude to? This may help to clarify what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't totally understand your question, but I'm thinking that the gist of what you are getting at is that you want to set the entire row all at once, rather than going letter by letter.

Assuming that what you want `set_Guess` to do is set the `row`-th row to `Guess`, then you can change it to something like this:

```
def set_Guess(self, row, Guess):
    self.matrix[row][:] = Guess
def get_Guess(self, row):
    return self.matrix[row][:]
```

So, basically:

```
def set_Guess(matrix, row, Guess):
    matrix[row][:] = Guess
    return matrix

def get_Guess(matrix, row):
    return matrix[row][:]

sentence = "hello world"
rows = 4
cols = len(sentence)
matrix = [['0'] * cols for row in range(rows)]

set_Guess(matrix, 1, "hello world")

for rn, row in enumerate(matrix):
    print('Row {rnum:d} = [{rvals}]'.format(rnum=rn+1, rvals=', '.join(row)))
```

This returns what you were looking for:

```
> python testmatrix.py
Row 1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Row 2 = [h, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d]
Row 3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Row 4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

That said, I suspect that for your particular application, you're not going about things the right way. I suggest maybe taking your application over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get more help with the design.